# Will Mirror Gallery make it impossible for your Mox Amber to produce mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Mirror Gallery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirror%20Gallery%5d) make it impossible to tap your [Mox Amber](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMox%20Amber%5d) for mana?

Comment: I slightly rewrote your question, because you can always tap your Mox Amber for mana, meaning it will always be a tap-activated mana ability. You just won't get any mana if you dont control any colored legendary creatures or planeswalkers.

Comment: @Hackworth I don't agree with that edit... your explanation of why you edited it actually involved you partially answering the actual question being asked. From the original question, it is not clear that the asker knows that they could always tap Mox Amber and simply misspoke.

Comment: @Hackworth So if you don't control any colored legendary creatures or planeswalkers, you can't tap it for colorless mana?

Comment: No, you can't. Colorless is not a color, and Mox Amber only gives you "any color" of mana.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No, legendary permanents are still legendary with Mirror Gallery on the field and will count for Mox Amber.**

Mirror Gallery only makes the "legend rule" not apply. It does not change any object in the game. In particular, it does not remove the "legendary" object supertype from anything.

The only way for Mox Amber to not produce mana is if you don't control any colored, legendary creatures or planeswalkers. Note that the game makes a distinction between types of mana and colors of mana. "Colorless" is a type of mana, but not a color, so Mox Amber will not produce any mana if you control only, for example, [Karn, Silver Golem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarn%2c%20Silver%20Golem%5d) or [Karn Liberated](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarn%20Liberated%5d).

> 106.1a There are five colors of mana: white, blue, black, red, and green.
>
> 106.1b There are six types of mana: white, blue, black, red, green, and colorless.
>
> 105.2c A colorless object has no color.