# Can you tap your Mox Amber for colorless mana with only a colorless legendary in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have one of the [Karn planeswalkers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&type=[Planeswalker]&name=+[Karn]) in play as my only legendary permanent can I then tap my [Mox Amber](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMox%20Amber%5d) for a colourless mana?

Comment: It's right on the Gatherer page... "If your legendary creatures and planeswalkers are all colorless, you can activate Mox Amber’s ability, but you won’t add any mana. Colorless is not a color."

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42273/will-mirror-gallery-make-it-impossible-for-your-mox-amber-to-produce-mana

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No.

Colorless is not a color; Mox Amber can never produce colorless because it says it produces "any color [...]".

> 105.4. If a player is asked to choose a color, they must choose one of the five colors. “Multicolored” is not a color. Neither is “colorless.”

Answer (score 8):

## Colorless is not a color

No, you cannot tap a Mox Amber for colorless mana. Mox Amber says

> {T}: Add one mana of any color among legendary creatures and planeswalkers you control.